# Use UIImageTags for a later use in a different ViewController? Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have a project where I have a Horizontal UIScrollView with 6 images all populated with a custom image.

When I drag and drop a image from the UIScrollView onto the HeaderImage at the top of the View. It changes the Headerimage of the Area that I dropped the Image from the ScrollView onto.

Now my challenge is that I have multiple images which are all different in my UIScrollView, But when I drag and drop any of the images in my UIScrollView onto the HeaderImage Area they all change to the same image.

How can I setup UIImage Tags so that when I setup my UIScrollView Images it saves the Image so that when dropped onto the HeaderImage area it shows the correct image or a different image.

Basically I want to be able to change the HeaderImage according to which image in my ScrollView is dropped onto it.

Below is my Code:

Any assistance is grealty appreciated.

Thanks Guys. I really am thankful for all the great help that has been given to me.

[image]
[image]

I setup my images for the scrollview in GalleryScrollView.m

```
- (void) addAttachment:(AttachmentItem *)attachment
{
// SAVE ATTACHMENT
[_attachments addObject:attachment];

// RESIZE CONTENT VIEW FOR INSERTINT NEW ATTACHMENT
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([_attachments count]*70, 70);

CGFloat startX = (70.0f * ((float)[_attachments count] - 1.0f) + padding);
CGFloat startY = 370;
CGFloat width = 64;
CGFloat height = 64;

GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height)];
btnAttachment.tag = [_attachments count];
btnAttachment.scrollParent = _scrollView;
btnAttachment.mainView = self.mainView;
btnAttachment.delegate = self;

if (attachment.type == 1){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"canadian-maple.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    int tag = btnAttachment.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    [imageView release];
}else if (attachment.type == 2){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    int tag = btnAttachment.tag;
     NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    [imageView release];
} else if (attachment.type == 3){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"canadian-maple.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    int tag = btnAttachment.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    [imageView release];
}
else if (attachment.type == 4){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    int tag = btnAttachment.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    [imageView release];
}
else if (attachment.type == 5){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"canadian-maple.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    int tag = btnAttachment.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    [imageView release];
}
else if (attachment.type == 6){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    int tag = btnAttachment.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    [imageView release];
}

[_scrollView addSubview:btnAttachment];
[btnAttachment release];

}
```

And Add them to my view here in HegakaDragAndDropRecycleBinViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.gallery.mainView = self.view;


AttachmentItem *item = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:1 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item];
[item release];

AttachmentItem *item2 = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:2 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item2];
[item2 release];

AttachmentItem *item3 = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:3 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item3];
[item3 release];

AttachmentItem *item4 = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:4 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item4];
[item4 release];

AttachmentItem *item5 = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:5 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item5];
[item5 release];

AttachmentItem *item6 = [[AttachmentItem alloc] initWithData:6 data:nil];
[self.gallery addAttachment:item6];
[item6 release];
}
```

And add the action of the TouchesEnded here

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:YES]){

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
    headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light-cherry.png"]];
    [self.mainView addSubview:headerImage];

    UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    animation.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - 32, self.center.y - 32, 40, 40);

    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem4.png"]
                                 ,nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [animation setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [animation startAnimating];
    [self.mainView addSubview:animation];
    [animation bringSubviewToFront:self.mainView];
    [animation release];
    ;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

} else{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

[self.delegate touchUp];
```

Okay So maybe i'm on the right track. Please could someone maybe guide me if this is the way to go, So I added:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

switch ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:YES]) {
    case 1:{

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
        headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"]];
        headerImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerImage.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        headerImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        headerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        headerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        [self.mainView addSubview:headerImage];

        UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        animation.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - 32, self.center.y - 32, 40, 40);

        animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem4.png"]
                                     ,nil];
        [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [animation setAnimationDuration:0.35];
        [animation startAnimating];
        [self.mainView addSubview:animation];
        [animation bringSubviewToFront:self.mainView];
        [animation release];
        ;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
        //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        }

        break;
    case 2:{

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
        headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recyclebin.png"]];
        headerImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerImage.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        headerImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        headerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        headerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        [self.mainView addSubview:headerImage];

        UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        animation.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - 32, self.center.y - 32, 40, 40);

        animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem1.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem2.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem3.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem4.png"]
                                     ,nil];
        [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [animation setAnimationDuration:0.35];
        [animation startAnimating];
        [self.mainView addSubview:animation];
        [animation bringSubviewToFront:self.mainView];
        [animation release];
        ;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
        //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        }
    }
    }
```

But nothing much happens

Comment: That is a *huge* amount of code. Please boil it down into a code sample that shows the problem you're having.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Cool I only showed the code that i think is necessary, you see my problem is that I don't know how to achieve -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {} for each of my Attachments or images in my scrollview else if (attachment.type == 6){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will Answer my own question then. After weeks of trying different methods. Turns out all I had to do is use this code. Thanks @NJones for putting me on the right track though.

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:YES]){

    if (self.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"View with tag %i was dropped onto trigger area",self.tag);

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
        headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light-cherry.png"]];
        headerImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerImage.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        headerImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        headerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        headerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        [self.mainView addSubview:headerImage];

    }
    else if (self.tag == 2)
    {

        NSLog(@"View with tag %i was dropped onto trigger area",self.tag);

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
        headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"]];
        headerImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        headerImage.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        headerImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        headerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        headerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        [self.mainView addSubview:headerImage];
    }
    UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    animation.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - 32, self.center.y - 32, 40, 40);

    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem4.png"]
                                 ,nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [animation setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [animation startAnimating];
    [self.mainView addSubview:animation];
    [animation bringSubviewToFront:self.mainView];
    [animation release];
    ;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

} else{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

[self.delegate touchUp];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The GalleryButton (a `UIView` subclass itself) is handling the touches. Tag is a property of a `UIView`. That means the tag is already there for you:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:YES]){
        // Log drag to recycle bin (or as you are calling it the header image view)
        NSLog(@"View with tag %i was dragged to the recycle bin",self.tag);

        .....
```

Comment: Your Correct. I'm declaring CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
        headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

As my image for all my draggable items. I know how to setup a uiimageview but don,t know how to set the image for Tag2 or Tag3 and so on..

Comment: and would I be able to use the above switch case function to do this. e.g if tag1 show headerimage  and if tag2 show headerimage1... that is the bit I am confused with:)

Answer (score 0):

on touchesBegan, save on WHICH 'AttachmentItem' you started!?